# plyr within loop: unexpected behavior

Tags: r, loops, plyr

I found an odd issue with plyr when using it inside a loop.
What I want to perform with this script is to iterate the plyr function with different input values (provided by the for loop) and store the results as a list of data.frames.

```
k=as.factor(c(rep("a",2), rep("b",2), rep("c",2), rep("d",2), rep("e",2)))
indata=data.frame(k)

outdata<-list()
for (i in 1:10){
  tempdata<-ddply(.data = indata, .variables = .(k), .fun = summarize, i=i)
  data[[i]]<-tempdata
  rm(tempdata)
}
data
```

I would expect it to produce a list of data.frames each produced within a single iteration of the loop, and therefore a single value of the loop variable.
What happens instead is that each of the data.frames looks identical, with each row having a sequential value of the loop variable.

Storing the loop variable into a separate one makes it work, but seems like an awkward workaround.

```
k=as.factor(c(rep("a",2), rep("b",2), rep("c",2), rep("d",2), rep("e",2)))
indata=data.frame(k)

outdata<-list()
for (i in 1:10){
  z=i
  tempdata<-ddply(.data = indata, .variables = .(k), .fun = summarize, i=i, z=z)
  data[[i]]<-tempdata
  rm(tempdata)
}
data
```

Any ideas on what's causing this odd behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This is a scoping issue. Functions within `ddply` (I believe `llply`) use `i` as a local variable and that's before your `i` in the search path. The easiest fix would be using `j` as the iterator:

```
for (j in 1:10)
```

However, I have no idea why you use `ddply` in your example. It doesn't seem necessary, so I assume it's only a toy example.

Comment: Thanks @Roland! Do you know what is the function of `i` within `__ply` functions? Is it used to keep track of "pieces" in which the input data is split?

Comment: Yes, it seems so. Look for yourself in `llply`.